# Disable virtualization on a Surface Book 3

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization, uefi, microsoft-surface

Does anyone know how to disable virtualization on a Surface Book 3? Most articles show going into the BIOS to change this setting however, Surface Book 3 uses UEFI instead of BIOS. When going into the UEFI/firmware settings, I see **no** option for virtualization. I need to disable this option to download important software I use for client files. I have read articles that suggest virtualization is needed on Surface Book 3 devices for firmware or security purposes. Is this true?

Comment: Basically all computers produced in the last decade use UEFI instead of BIOS, people are just using the old name. Particular UEFI may be missing some options, though. But it shouldn't be required to disable virtualization for some software to work. Are you sure that's a problem? The software could check if it's being virtualized - that's a reasonable thing sometimes - but it shouldn't matter if you're capable of virtualizing something else.

Comment: Please provide more information.  Hardware Virtualization being enabled should not prevent any software from working.  By default hardware virtualization is enabled on Surface products.  If there is no option to disable it within the firmware settings then it cannot be disabled.  Understand what you are trying to accomplish specifically might help us answer your question.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. When attempting to install the software, an error message states, "This software cannot be installed on a virtual machine." The support specialist gave me two possible causes: (1) hyper-v, which I have disabled and (2) virtualization is enabled. They claim the reason that the software isn't downloading is because the software thinks I am downloading it on a remote computer, therefore, giving the single-user license access to multiple users.

Comment: Sounds like it's in fact trying to prevent usage in VMs. Enabled virtualization itself shouldn't trigger this error. Please double-check that Hyper-V is not installed. Are you using any emulators, Android SDK or WSL?

Comment: That is correct, and I think that will be fine to prevent in my case. I will double-check now. I don't believe any of that is in use. Do you have any suggests on areas I might need to check? I am checking for hyper-v under "windows features" section.

Comment: Instead of submitting additional commentary you should edit and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on surface book -2 and found the solution. Control Panel > Program Features > Turn windows features on or off > Un-select "Virtual Machine Platform", then reboot computer.